# How to fix awful font rendering in Firefox 55 on Debian Buster/testing?

Tags: firefox, fonts

I upgraded from Debian stable (Stretch) to testing (Buster) today, which went without a hitch. All applications work fine, except Firefox, which has awful font rendering: text is often hard to read and has artifacts. It gets better with (much) higher zoom values than 100%, but artifacts are always visible. (I'm still running Firefox 55 because I'm missing lots of add-ons in quantum. Many still cannot be implemented in the new system because APIs are todo.)

Screenshot I've found online with the same issue, except this is for Firefox 52:

http://z-issue.com/blog_imgs/tech/linux/fonts/mozilla_rendering/linux_firefox_thunderbird_ugly_fonts_skia_cairo.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out the solution by piecing together different sources, but later found that it's nicely described here: http://z-issue.com/wp/ugly-fonts-in-mozilla-firefox-and-thunderbird-under-linux-skia-and-cairo/

Basically, in `about:config`, change `gfx.content.azure.backends` and `gfx.canvas.azure.backends` from `skia` to `cairo`. Then restart Firefox.

[This bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1400721) appears to be related, the target of which is 57. If you don't mind losing some addons, you should try upgrading.

Comment: Can I upvote myself? More than two years later on a different computer, much newer Firefox version, newer Debian version, the issue suddenly appeared and I knew to look for this answer and it actually worked :D