# Firefox Quantum on Debian stretch font rendering problems

Tags: linux, debian, firefox, fonts, fontconfig

I install firefox «Quantum» 60.0.2 (64bits) on Debian GNU/Linux Stretch via **snap**, follow [this](https://www.linuxbabe.com/debian/install-firefox-quantum-debian-9-stretch) and I have big font rendering problems with this version of Firefox. [image: Here] a screen cap of Jupyter Notebook header with Firefox Quantum and [image: here] a screen cap of the same page with Firefox ESR.
I try all solutions I could find :

- add a `.fonts.conf` like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226831/how-can-i-improve-the-font-rendering-in-firefox);
- [change](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/425793/how-to-fix-awful-font-rendering-in-firefox-55-on-debian-buster-testing) `gfx.canvas.azure.backends` and `gfx.content.azure.backends` from `skia` to `cairo` first, and to `direct2d1.1,cairo,skia` finally;
- try to deactivate graphic acceleration;
- set the same font as default (`serif` 16, `serif`, `sans-serif`, `monospace` 12).

But nothing works ! Perhaps I miss something but I couldn't find anything else.

Comment: Fill a [bugreport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Bug_writing_guidelines), if you've found a bug.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a bug yet. I have post the same question in mozilla support forum.

Answer (score 1):

1 - In your user directory, create a nex subdirectory:
  mkdir -p ~/.config/fontconfig

2 - With a text editor, create the file font.conf (~/.config/fontconfig/font.conf) and paste this content :

`<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
<fontconfig>
 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="rgba">
   <const>rgb</const>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="hinting">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="hintstyle">
   <const>hintslight</const>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="antialias">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
  <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="lcdfilter">
    <const>lcddefault</const>
  </edit>
  </match>
</fontconfig>`

Save this file (~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf)

3- Restart Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I change the install method and choose to download the `.tar.bzip2` archive directly from mozilla. I put the `firefox/` dir in `/opt` create a link : `>sudo ln -s /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox-quantum` and add a specific `firefox-quantum.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications/` folder and no more font rendering problems.

arnome.